# Adding image to a QLabel when it is clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project, in which i am trying to add an image to a QLabel when it is clicked. I read a few articles on how to make a Clickable QLabel, but adding an image seems to be tricky. Any way of doing it?

EDIT 1-

I am making a simple tic tac toe game in QT. So i made a grid layout of 9 QLabels. And i want to add an image to the corresponding QLabel (O or X) when it is clicked.
I made a 2d array to check the winning status as well.
Here is the code of mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

//QPixmap imageO("C:/Users/user/Documents/tictactoe/o.png");
//QPixmap imageX("C:/Users/user/Documents/tictactoe/x.png");
char a[3][3],turn_player='O';

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    int i,j;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            a[i][j]='-';
    }
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
     ui->setupUi(this);
     windowstart();
     this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    grid = new QGridLayout(centralWidget);
    for(int  i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            labels[i][j]= new ClickableLabel("",this);
            grid->addWidget(labels[i][j], i+1, j);
            labels[i][j]->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            looks(i,j);
        }
    }
    play();
}

void MainWindow::windowstart()
{
    setWindowTitle("TIC-TAC-TOE");
    setFixedSize(500,500);
    QPixmap bkgnd("C:/Users/user/Documents/tictactoe/background.jpg");
    bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
    this->setPalette(palette);
}


void MainWindow::looks(int i,int j)
{
      labels[i][j]->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: #000000; color: white; font:20pt; font-weight:500; border-radius: 10px;}");
}

void MainWindow::play()
{
    //int count=0;
    for( ; ; )
        {
            move_Player('O');
            count++;
            if(woncheck('O')==true)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Game Over"),tr("Player A(O) won."));
                break;
            }
            if(count==9)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Game Over"),tr("Player   A(O) won."));
                break;
            }
            move_Player('X');
            count++;
            if(woncheck('X')==true)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Game Over"),tr("Player B(X) won."));
                break;
            }
        }
}
void MainWindow::move_Player(char ch)
{
    if(ch=='O')
        //set picture of O
    else
        //set picture of X
}




bool MainWindow::woncheck (char test)
{
    int i,j,counter1,counter2,counter3,counter4;
        for(i=0;i<3;i+=1)
        {
            counter1=0;counter2=0;counter3=0,counter4=0;
            for(j=0;j<3;j+=1)
            {
                if(a[i][j]==test)
                    counter1++;
                if(a[j][i]==test)
                    counter2++;
                if(a[j][j]==test)
                    counter3++;
                if(a[j][4-j]==test)
                    counter4++;
            }
            if(counter1==3||counter2==3||counter3==3||counter4==3)
                 return true;
        }
        return false;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I have a class ClickableLabel as well, which inherits from QLabel and emits the clicked signal and nothing more. I also thought of adding the function to add image when QLabel is clicked to the ClickableLabel class, but couldn't figure how to actually to do it.

Comment: I've answered below with the call to use, but your question is short on details. What seems to be tricky about it?

Answer (score 1):

The method to add an image is `QLabel::setPixmap.` ([reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop))